# Help shortening repeated jQuery event listeners

Tags: jquery

My code repeats as follows:

```
$("#school-name").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", {
    width: 218,
    delay: 300,
    selectFirst: false,
    resultsClass: 'ac_results_class',
    loadingClass: 'ac_loading',
    formatItem: function(data)
    {
        if (data[2]) 
        { 
            return data[0] + '<small>' + data[2] + '</small>'; 
        }
        else
        {
            return data[0];
        }
    }
});

$("#school-name-optional").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", {
    width: 358,
    delay: 300,
    selectFirst: false,
    resultsClass: 'ac_results_book',
    loadingClass: 'ac_loading',
    formatItem: function(data)
    {
        if (data[2]) 
        { 
            return data[0] + '<small>' + data[2] + '</small>'; 
        }
        else
        {
            return data[0];
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, the two event listeners only differ in a couple of parameters.  How should I shorten this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, shortening this code makes it less readable and as configuration parameters outside the reach of *DRY* (Don't Repeat Yourself).

With that said, to answer your questions, there are two quick things you could do.

First, break out the `formatItem` into a generic function instead of an anonymous function.

```
function myFormatItem(data) {
...
}
```

then use:

```
formatItem: myFormatItem
```

Second, you could create the base configuration options, then extend them.

```
var config = {width: 218,
        delay: 300,
        selectFirst: false,
        resultsClass: 'ac_results_book',
        loadingClass: 'ac_loading',
        formatItem: myFormatItem}

$("#school-name").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", config);

var config2 = config;
config2.width = 358;
$("#school-name").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", config2);
```

Comment: So you wouldn't recommend shortening it in those ways?

Comment: I guess it depends. I like to adhere to the *DRY Principle* as much as possible. But, as noted, not when it makes the code *harder* to maintain. If you want to shorten it, of course I stand by my answer. I also think **icktoofay** is a good answer. The others are similar approaches or prove my point about over complicating it, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Break it into a function.

```
schoolNameAutocomplete($("#school-name"), 218);
schoolNameAutocomplete($("#school-name-optional"), 358);
function schoolNameAutocomplete(element, width) {
    element.autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", {
        width: width,
        delay: 300,
        selectFirst: false,
        resultsClass: 'ac_results_book',
        loadingClass: 'ac_loading',
        formatItem: function(data)
        {
            if (data[2]) 
            { 
                return data[0] + '<small>' + data[2] + '</small>'; 
            }
            else
            {
                return data[0];
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 good approach - better encapsulates the similarities without making a configuration mess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an anonymous object, save the object to a var and modify it accordingly for the different calls.

I made a facade to jQuery UI's dialog functionality where I had to do something similar:

```
function createDefaultOptions(type) {
    var 
    options = {
        dialogClass: 'webDialog',
        width: 300,
        callback: function() { },
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeText: '',
        zIndex: 10000,
        hide: { effect: 'slide', duration: 500 }
    },

    okButton = {
        OK: function() {
            options.callback({ button: 'OK' });
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },

    yesNoButtons = {
        Yes: function() {
            options.callback({ button: 'Yes' });
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        No: function() {
            options.callback({ button: 'No' });
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    };

    switch (type) {
        case 'general':
            options.title = 'Message';
            options.buttons = okButton;
            break;
        case 'error':
            options.title = 'Error';
            options.buttons = okButton;
            options.dialogClass += ' webDialogError';
            break;
        case 'success':
            options.title = 'Success';
            options.buttons = okButton;
            options.dialogClass += ' webDialogSuccess';
            break;
        case 'confirm':
            options.title = 'Confirm';
            options.buttons = yesNoButtons;
            options.dialogClass += ' webDialogConfirm';
            break;
    }

    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a generic function for the formatItem handler and then use it as a reference:

```
function doSomething(){

}
//...
formatItem: doSomething
```

that way the only thing you need to change are the basic properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var params = {
    delay: 300,
    selectFirst: false,
    loadingClass: 'ac_loading',
    formatItem: function(data)
    {
        if (data[2])
        {
            return data[0] + '<small>' + data[2] + '</small>';
        }
        else
        {
            return data[0];
        }
    }
};

$("#school-name").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", $.extend(params, {
    width: 218,
    resultsClass: 'ac_results_class'
}));

$("#school-name-optional").autocomplete("/ajax/campus_ajax.php", $.extend(params, {
    width: 358,
    resultsClass: 'ac_results_book'
}));
```